# install postgresql database on server and run gui application on another pc client

Tags: python, postgresql, lan, dhcp

I have created 2 GUI applications using pyqt5 and postgresql database

one of them a read a write application and the 2 ND read only

I want to install the database on one computer that contain the application read only and in another computer the application read a write

Note that the 2 PC are connected using DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) server the code I use to connect my application to the database is like this

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                               password="password",
                               host="localhost", 
                               port="5432",
                               database="SIFAX")
```

How I can configure the postgres database and my code, making it possible

Comment: `'host'` should specify the DNS hostname of the machine that's running the database.  If your network does not have any DNS then you might need to ensure that the db server has a static IP address.

Comment: The server dose doesn't have a DNS when I install postgresql in one of the PC connected to the server the application runs perfectly, but on another computer connected to the same server dose not run its like there is no database at all

Answer (score 0):

find a solution

first in the file

```
pg_hba.conf
```

in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data
add the ip adress of the client pc like this

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             x.x.x.x/32              md5#ip of the first client 
host    all             all             x.x.x.x/32              md5#ip of the 2nd client
```

and in the code of gui used in the server it will be like this

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                               password="password",
                               host="localhost", 
                               port="5432",
                               database="database")
```

and the code of the gui used in the client pc it will be like this

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                               password="password",
                               host="ip adress of the server", 
                               port="5432",
                               database="database")
```